# Updating table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been struggling with getting this code to work for a few days. If you could offer any solutions I would really appreciate it.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()


If IsNull(NewSupBox.Value) Or IsNull(NewNumberBox.Value) Then
MsgBox ("All fields must be filled")
GoTo ErrorExit
End If

If Not IsNull(DLookup("SupplierNumber", "SupGenInfo ", "SupGenInfo.SupplierNumber =" &        NewSupBox)) = Then
MsgBox ("This supplier number already exists. You can edit the current record on the Edit       supplier page.")
GoTo ErrorExit
End If

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("select * from SupGenInfo")

rec.AddNew
rec("SupplierNumber") = Me.NewSupBox.Value
rec("SupplierName") = Me.NewNameBox.Value
rec.Update

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing



MsgBox "Records added successfully."
ErrorExit:

End Sub
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that I am not getting any error message. The command will simply not add a new record to my table.

Edit2: The code above will output the msg "Records Added Successfully" when i remove the following block of code.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SupGenInfo")

rec.AddNew
rec("SupplierNumber") = Me.NewSupBox
rec("SupplierName") = Me.NewNameBox
rec.Update

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

It is when this code is included that my command click becomes unresponsive.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: When I click the command nothing happens. My table is left unaffected and there are no error messages. I have similar code to this running in my database on a different form that works perfectly fine.

Comment: You tagged it as VBA? What application uses this code? Also where did `CurrentDb` come from? Are you trying to use/utilize **ADODB** or is it something else? Please clarify your question and add relevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you are reading a table (for display purposes) with your `select * ...` statement, then you're adding a new record to that list rather than the actual database. When you open `OpenRecordset`, just supply the table name, not a whole SQL query shebang...

I created a new table, so edit this code to match your parameters/values, otherwise this has been tested to work:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

rec.AddNew
rec("Field1") = 1234
rec("Field2") = "blah2"
rec("Field3") = "blah3"
rec.Update

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Tested this code and it is not working for me. Since the code is working on your end, I am worried that I have a more complicated issue.

Comment: I have Access 2010 and it may not refresh the table instantly (I had to close and reopen the table, but it did work...)

Comment: I just read your edit, this may sound silly, but can you check write permissions on the file? Is it a local DB or one sitting on the network? VBA might run differently if the DB is on a network location (for security reasons...).

Comment: One other thing to try is debug your code line by line (haha, why didn't I think of this first) or add messageboxes with different messages after each line of code that causes trouble and see where the hiccup happens.

Comment: Is it possible that there are specific permissions for writing to a table from a form? I am able to delete records with my form but not append to them. I can also append to a form if I use just a query but the query will not work if i try to run it with VBA.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific permission. File system generally cares if a user can write to a file or not, but not what can be written/erased... At my work I was working on a database project and we placed the DB (`SQLite` database, not `Access`) on a shared network folder and I had the IT give the engineering group the write permissions to the folder, but not erase permissions (except me), so everyone who uses my app would be writing to the database, but they can't delete the database file. Hope this clears it up.